# Using a variable in a SQL expression within Make Feature Layer function

Tags: arcpy, sql, feature-layer

I need to make a function to call in another script to  count the buildings within an area using a field value UseCode

Here is what I have with my test script. I know the make feature layer is not working because it gives me the result of 7 no matter what use code I use, that feature class the only one that should give 7 is use code 3

```
#Count Buildings
def CountBuildings(bldgfc,bldgcode,boxfc):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(bldgfc, "bldgs", '[UseCode] = ' + bldgcode, wrkspc,)
    sfbl = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation("bldgs", 'HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN', boxfc)
    bldgcount = arcpy.management.GetCount(sfbl)
    return bldgcount

#test script
print(CountBuildings("BldgFootprints",'0',"FireBoxMap_0"))
```

wrkspc is my workspace I defined it earlier in the script. the issue I think lies in this '[UseCode] = ' + bldgcode
bldgcode is a user input, but I am lost on how to include that in a SQL expression.

Comment: String math isn't best practice (slow and subject to error); use `str.format()` instead. It's unclear if your data type is integer or string or something else. It also makes a significant difference as to the data provider asto how columns are referenced. Please [Rdit] the Question

Comment: the data type is long int in arc

Comment: @vince that fixed it thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Vince I was able to get it. Was a formatting issue.

```
    #Count Buildings
def CountBuildings(bldgfc,bldgcode,boxfc):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(bldgfc,"bldgs",'UseCode ='+format(bldgcode))
    sfbl = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation("bldgs",'HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN', boxfc)
    bldgcount = arcpy.management.GetCount(sfbl)
    return bldgcount

#test script
print(CountBuildings("BldgFootprints",'3',"FireBoxMap_0"))
```